# Error al imprimir un valor de un diccionario, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, diccionarios

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde creo una función para que el usuario seleccione una clave de un diccionario y dicha función le imprime el valor correspondiente de dicha clave.

**El problema** está en que al ingresar la clave del diccionario, imprime su valor correctamente, pero debajo tambien imprime un `None`, y no sé por qué ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Tambien si hay una manera mas eficiente de escribir este código, ¿Puedes compartirla? Me ayudaría bastante.

```
def imprimir_valor(n):
    if seleccion == 'a':
        print(n.get('a'))
    elif seleccion == 'b':
        print(n.get('b'))
    elif seleccion == 'c':
        print(n.get('c'))
    elif seleccion == 'd':
        print(n.get('d'))
    elif seleccion == 'e':
        print(n.get('e'))
    elif seleccion == 'f':
        print(n.get('f'))
    else:
        print(f'Tu llave {seleccion} no se encuentra en el diccionario')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dict = {'a' : 'String', 'b' : 10, 'c' : 3.14, 'd' : False, 'e': [1,2,3], 'f' : (4,5,6)}
    seleccion= input("Ingrese entre una llave entre a y f para sabeer su valor en el dict: ")
    impreso = imprimir_valor(my_dict)
    print(impreso)
```

Answer (score 2):

El "error" es porque `impreso = imprimir_valor(my_dict)` está esperando un valor de la función y no se lo estás retornando (porque no tiene `return`), así que imprime `None`.

No necesitas ese montón de `if` para comparar si la llave existe.

```
>>> my_dict = {'a' : 'String', 'b' : 10, 'c' : 3.14, 'd' : False, 'e': [1,2,3], 'f' : (4,5,6)}
>>> 'a' in my_dict.keys() # ¿Existe 'a' como clave?
True
>>> 'z' in my_dict.keys() # ¿Existe 'z' como clave?
False
>>> my_dict['c'] # traer el valor de la clave 'c'
3.14
```

Con lo anterior, tu código se puede reducir a:

```
my_dict = {'a' : 'String', 'b' : 10, 'c' : 3.14, 'd' : False, 'e': [1,2,3], 'f' : (4,5,6)}
seleccion = input("Ingrese entre una llave entre a y f...: ")
if seleccion in my_dict.keys():
    print(my_dict[seleccion])
else:
    print("Error, llave no valida")
```

Answer (score 2):

La explicación del error de @aeportugal es perfecta! Al no haber un `return` la función es una función *vacia* por lo que devuelve `None`. Por poner otra solución a este error, tu código podría quedar así:

```
my_dict = {'a' : 'String', 'b' : 10, 'c' : 3.14, 'd' : False, 'e': [1,2,3], 'f' : (4,5,6)}
seleccion = input("Ingrese entre una llave entre a y f...: ")
print(my_dict.get(seleccion, "Error, llave no valida"))
```

**Ejemplo salida para "a"**: `String`

**Ejemplo salida para "bz"**: `Error, llave no valida`

El método `.get()` de los diccionarios se le puede pasar el primer parámetro que sería la clave a buscar, y el segundo, que es el parámetro `default`. Sirve para crear una devolución por defecto en caso de que no encuentre esa clave, que es justo lo que necesitas.

Por defecto, ese parámetro `default` devuelve `None` y cuando devuelve `None` Python genera un `KeyError`. Si quieres saber más puedes ver la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)